# wordpress get_posts ordered by custom field which is a custom date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date, custom-post-type

i have a custom post type for members and the birth date is saved like 01.01.2013

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'mitglied',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_key'      => 'geburtsdatum',
    'meta_value'    => date("d.m.Y"),
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$geburtstage = get_posts ( $args );
```

i want a list with the birthdays of the members ordered by month and day like this

- 4th of january, person 10
- 8th of march, person 2
- ...
- 1st of december, person 3

with the code above the list is ordered by day

- 1st of december, person 3
- 4th of january, person 10
- 8th of march, person 2

also important is, that the ordering is not influenced by the year of birth

Comment: wordpress questions ARE ok here, but for future use, there is a StackExchange site specific to WP which I've found to be very good.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem is that by storing a formatted date instead of Unix Time, Wordpress' ordering options aren't going to be of any help for you. You'll need to either come up with your own sorting method, or hook into the save action and convert a post's DOB metadata to Unix using strtotime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my task is not solveable with get_posts only, so i did it in 3 steps.

First, i used get_posts to get all members

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'mitglied',
);
$geburtstage = get_posts ( $args );
```

Then filled an array with the data. For sorting I made a timestamp with the day and month of the birthday, but the actual year.
Although with this solution it would not have been necessary, I changed the date format to yyyy-mm-dd. @barakadam explained in his answer to my question how to do this.
I use the wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields, so I fetch the custom fields with get_field()

```
$mitglieder = array( array() );
$i = 0;
foreach($geburtstage as $post){
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $datum = explode( "-",get_field('geburtsdatum') );

    $mitglieder[$i]['orderby'] = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int)$datum[1], (int)$datum[2], date('Y'));
    $mitglieder[$i]['name'] = get_field( 'name' );
    $i++;
}
```

The last step is using array_multisort to get the intended order

```
foreach ($mitglieder as $key => $row) {
    $dates[$key] = $row['orderby'];
}
array_multisort($dates, SORT_ASC, $mitglieder);
```

Thanks to @barakadam and @Christopher for participating.

Answer (score 4):

You have stored the date in the wrong format in your custom field. You should have used a UNIX stamp or else a format like Y-m-d, which allows to sort chronologically. 
The only solution you have now is to retrieve your results without sorting them (forget `'order' => 'ASC'`) but also without limiting them (because your date limit is not working even if it looks like it does), create an array with all that, convert the date time as a UNIX timestamp (using `strtotime`) and sort by date...
But my real advice would be to refactor your site using timestamps or properly formated dates (Y-m-d). You could create a loop that goes through every post and replaces the value of your custom field with the equivalent value in UNIX, using this :

```
$oldvalue = get_post_meta($post_id, 'geburtsdatum', true);  
update_post_meta($post_id, 'geburtsdatum', strtotime($old_value));
```

Please backup your database before this or at least make a test on ore or two posts, but this should solve it. Then you will be able to later use :

```
date("d.m.Y", $yourunixstamp)
```

to get formated dates.

And then, also, your previous code will just become :

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'       => 'mitglied',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'meta_key'      => 'geburtsdatum',
'meta_value'    => time(),
'meta_compare' => '>',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$geburtstage = get_posts ( $args );
```

Comment: thanks for this, i already thought of changing the date format, but with the update_post_meta it was quite easy and fast! the only thing now is, how can i sort the dates only by month and day? so it doesnt matter if someone is born in 1950 or 2000 - the one who is born in an earlier month should be on top of the list

Comment: Then you should store the day, month and year in separate fields (+ keep a field with the UNIX stamp) or have a field with "m-d" (month and day -- in this case, you will automatically get your list the way you want). (again, you can use `add_post_meta` in a loop, retrieving the value of `geburtsdatum` as you stored it and feeding the month and day in another custom field).